# Adobe AIR, Native Extension load only specific device

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I've got a native extension for Android. The functionality of this native extension is already implemented in the Air SDK for iOS. So I use the SDK functions on iOS and the native extension for Android.

The native extension doesn't support iOS, which makes sense, because the functionality is already implementent in the Air SDK for iOS.

When I start the App on Android everything works fine. But if I start the App on iOS I got the following error

```
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class com.afterisk.shared.ane.lib::GCMEvent could not be found
```

I splitted the code for each device in different classes. But it seems that Air try to compile the code for Android anyway.

Are there any way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: You need to use separate app descriptors for iOS and Android packages and have different sets of ANEs

Comment: Don't compile your ios with those anes and code reference that's quite simple.

Comment: Looks like you have GCMEvent referenced somewhere in your code and since the ANE is not compiled in the iOS Version the app can't find this class. You'd need to remove the reference from your code for the iOS Version - maybe by using Interfaces + dependency injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I managed to solve my problem with different app descriptors.